# Download multiple items at once. Returns result whenever finished them all

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, deferred

I am trying to download multiple items at once.

Assuming I want to download 10 items and each item takes 1 second to download, I do not want it to take 10 seconds, but 1.

Sounds like a coroutine problem, right?

Right now, it looks like:

```
suspend fun getLanguageDictionaryDeferred(language: String): Result<JSONObject> {
    val namespacesResponse = api.getNamespaces(language)
    return if (namespacesResponse.isSuccessful) {
        Result.success(getJson(namespacesResponse.body(), language))
    } else {
        Result.error("Error: ${namespacesResponse.code()}")
    }
}

private suspend fun getJson(namespaces: List<Namespace>?, language: String): JSONObject {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    namespaces?.forEach {
        load(it, language)
    }
    return jsonObject
}
```

I think that the problem is on these functions. I need to download them async but whenever finished, notify with a result.

I was thinking that might be the problem on the `getJson` function with `Deferred` objects to call the `await` function. But how would I call the at once and wait them all at once? What if I do not know the number of items on the `forEach` loop?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

While doing tests, I found that we can await all like this: (although, takes about the same)

```
private suspend fun getJson(namespaces: List<Namespace>?, language: String): JSONObject {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    namespaces?.map { async { load(it, language) } }?.awaitAll()
    return jsonObject
}
```

But, I am not sure if this is done correctly and warning is displayed:

`Ambiguous coroutineContext due to CoroutineScope receiver of suspend function`

Comment: I don't know how to gave you answer for your question exactly, but I'll show you how suspend function can await the code, ```suspend fun name(...){  ....   delay(1000) } ```

Comment: Definitely not what I am looking for. I know how to delay. I want to download them all at once. I don’t know if on the **EDIT** answers it correctly or not. And why is that.